# preventDefault create issue while calling again jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using below code to execute a method and it working fine.

But when i tried it again its not working until i reopen or refresh the page.

so it works only first time. I also tried unbind also but its not working.

```
if ($('#myModal').is(':visible')) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $("#ok_button").click();
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }

    }
```

i have tried this also but not working

```
$('#ok_button').unbind('click');
```